# How to sort values according to their parameter name and create a table in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, sorting

I have a huge list of strings (similar to *strs* given below, but much larger). The time stamps are given for each column. 
I'd like to efficiently convert it to a table format (numpy array or pandas dataframe or ...) according to the one below.

```
strs = ['time', 'stamp1', 'a', '1',    'b', '2',    'c', '3', 
        'time', 'stamp2', 'a', '11',   'b', '22',                'd', '4', 
        'time', 'stamp3', 'a', '111',  'b', '222',  'c', '333', 
        'time', 'stamp4', 'a', '1111', 'b', '2222', 'c', '3333', 'd', '444']
```

| time | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stamp1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| stamp2 | 11 | 22 |  | 4 |
| stamp3 | 111 | 222 | 333 |  |
| stamp4 | 1111 | 2222 | 3333 | 444 |

Comment: How the table is stored does not matter much. I am mainly curious if there is an efficient way to convert the given list to the given table.

Comment: Is there any column (e.g. `time`) that is guaranteed to be filled for every row?  (Otherwise it seems like you could have ambiguous situations where it's not clear whether two entries are on the same row or not.)  Or is aligning the data into rows even important?

Comment: @Samwise time and corresponding stamp are always given

Comment: I'd parse pairs into a dict, and yield that record every time you get a new "time". I can't help with the numpy part, but it looks like np.asarray is not what you want, even after you break it down into separate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

records = []
record = {strs[0]: strs[1]}
for key, value in zip(strs[2::2], strs[3::2]):
    if key == "time":
        records.append(record)
        record = {key: value}
    else:
        record[key] = value
else:
    records.append(record)
    
table = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Result:

```
     time     a     b     c    d
0  stamp1     1     2     3  NaN
1  stamp2    11    22   NaN    4
2  stamp3   111   222   333  NaN
3  stamp4  1111  2222  3333  444
```

Or do it via a generator:

```
import pandas as pd

def records(lst):
    record = {lst[0]: lst[1]}
    for key, value in zip(lst[2::2], lst[3::2]):
        if key == "time":
            yield record
            record = {key: value}
        else:
            record[key] = value
    else:
        yield record

table = pd.DataFrame(records(strs))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first process this list as a dictionary and then turn the dictionary into a `pandas` DataFrame. But first you'll need to fill in the missing values because the lists will need to be the same size to create the dataframe. I did this by splitting the `strs` list into sub lists based on the appearance of the `time` string. I then also got the column names by slicing over the list every other value starting at 0 and then passing it to a `set` to get only the unique values.

I then looped over the list of sublists that represent our rows and if there wasn't a value representative of the column in the list I added it and gave it a `NaN` value. Once the list of sublists had all the values for every column. I then looped over it and assigned the values to the `dict` to create the dataframe. Once the dictionary was created just passing it to `from_dict` will create the columns based on key, value pairs in the dictionary.

The only issue is the columns aren't in order so I reordered them.

```py
strs = ['time', 'stamp1', 'a', '1',    'b', '2',    'c', '3', 
        'time', 'stamp2', 'a', '11',   'b', '22',                'd', '4', 
        'time', 'stamp3', 'a', '111',  'b', '222',  'c', '333', 
        'time', 'stamp4', 'a', '1111', 'b', '2222', 'c', '3333', 'd', '444']

# splitting the lists by the 'time' string since thats the start of a new row
col_names = set(strs[::2])
Lsub = []
L2 = []
for e in strs:
    if e == 'time':
        if Lsub: 
            L2.append(Lsub)
        Lsub = [e]
    else:
        Lsub.append(e)
L2.append(Lsub)

#fill in missing values
for sublist in L2:
    for col in col_names:
        if col not in sublist:
            sublist.extend([col, np.nan])


# create dictionary to assign values too
df_dict = {k: [] for k in col_names}

for x in L2:
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if x[i-1] in col_names:
            df_dict[x[i-1]].append(y)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
cols = ['time'] + sorted([x for x in col_names if x != 'time'])
df = df[cols]
print(df)
```

Which gives this output:

```
     time     a     b     c    d
0  stamp1     1     2     3  NaN
1  stamp2    11    22   NaN    4
2  stamp3   111   222   333  NaN
3  stamp4  1111  2222  3333  444
```